# Parametrized Rmarkdown: Use value of param A in definition of param B

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Conceptually I want to do something like this:

````
---
title: Fun With Params
output: html_document
params:
   x: 1
   y: !r params$x + 1
--- 

```{r}
params
```
````

That is I want to use the value of one parameter in the definition of another one.

This does not work. It renders though with an `Error`:

> ```
> Error in eval(expression) : object 'params' not found
> Calls: <Anonymous> -> eval -> eval
>
> Warning message:
> In yaml::yaml.load(yaml, handlers = knit_params_handlers(evaluate = evaluate),  :
>   an error occurred when handling type 'r'; using default handler
> ```

And the document looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of the rendered RMarkdown where params$y renders to the (unevaluated) text]

Basically, this tells me that in the moment the YAML header is parsed `params` does not yet exist and `parms$x` cannot be evaluated, hence it returns simply the string.

I could assign a default value (`NULL` say) and push the logic to my first chunk. This, however, has the annoying drawback that in RStudio I should not forget to run this very chunk to get the proper value of `params$y`. This is of course not an issue when rendering the full document, but annoying if I want (for whatever reason) to run some chunks (not necessarily in order) interactively.

Thus, is there a way how I could use another param in the definition of another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is wholly satisfactory, but one approach would be to use `dplyr::lst()` which allows the sequential building of objects.  This would result in a nested parameter object however.

````
---
title: Fun With Params
output: html_document
params: 
  myparams: !r dplyr::lst(x = 1, y = x + 1)
--- 

```{r}
params
```
````

[image]

Alternatively, you could put some placeholders in your YAML header and replace these with a `render()` call:

````
---
title: Fun With Params
output: html_document
params:
  x: NA
  y: NA
--- 

```{r}
params
```
````

And use:

```
rmarkdown::render("funwithparams.rmd", params = dplyr::lst(x = 1, y = x + 1))
```

Giving:

[image]